# Fast convert CLOB to String without encoding in java

Tags: java, string, oracle, jdbc, clob

I have a problem: in my app CLOB converts to string very slow. For example, convert VARCHAR2(40) to string takes 0,001ms, convert CLOB(~1600) to string takes 0.8.
For converting to 1600/40=40 times more bytes, need 0.8/0.001=800 times more time (20 times slower)
I convert with

```
ResultSet rs = ... 
while (rs.next()){ 
   Clob clob = rs.getClob(3); 
   String s = clob.getSubString(1, MAX_TEXTITEM_LENGTH); 
   ...
```

Opening `Clob.getCharacterStream()` take many time too...
I think, that problem in encoding or something else? Need advice!

Oracle database use UTF-8 charset.

**UPDATE.** The trouble in: "By drivers implement a Clob object using an SQL locator(CLOB), which means that a Clob object contains a logical pointer to the SQL CLOB data rather than the data itself." How i can take CLOB value inline (when i use next())?

P.S. Sry for bad english.

Comment: Why aren't you doing `dbms_lob.substr` in the query instead, then using `rs.getString()`? If the value is more than 4k then you're pulling more data than you need. Or is `MAX_TESTITEM_LENGTH` higher than the 4k `varchar2` limit?

Comment: Because sometimes CLOB size more than 64K, but offer it is 1-2K

Comment: But you're only using part of it - can `MAX_TEXTITEM_LENGTH` be more than 4k? If it can't then you might as well perform the substring in the DB and only transfer the data you actually want?

Comment: Yes, it can be more than 4k, because i need transfer whole table.

Answer (score 1):

I try with this method:

```
public static String clobToString(Clob data) {
    long dataL = System.currentTimeMillis();
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    if (data != null) {
        Reader reader = null;
        BufferedReader br = null;
        try {
            reader = data.getCharacterStream();
            br = new BufferedReader(reader);
            String line;
            while (null != (line = br.readLine())) {
                sb.append(line);
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            logger.error(getClassAndMethodNameRuntime(), e);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            logger.error(getClassAndMethodNameRuntime(), e);
        } finally {
            closeObject(br);
            closeObject(reader);
        }
    }
    logger.trace("CLOB CONVERSION TIME1 ms: " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - dataL) + " Character: " + sb.length());
    return sb.toString();
}
```

AND

```
public static String clobToString2(Clob data) {
    long dataL = System.nanoTime();
    String result = "";
    int MAX_TEXTITEM_LENGTH = 8000;

    if (data != null) {
        try {
            result = data.getSubString(1, MAX_TEXTITEM_LENGTH);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            logger.error(getClassAndMethodNameRuntime(), e);
        }
    }
    logger.trace("CLOB CONVERSION TIME2 ms: " + ((double)(System.nanoTime() - dataL)) / 1000000 + " Character: " + result.length());
    return result;
}
```

The conversion time is very variable:

- CLOB CONVERSION TIME1 ms: 87.493707 Character: 7976
- CLOB CONVERSION TIME2 ms: 29.231168 Character: 8000
- CLOB CONVERSION TIME1 ms: 14.849225 Character: 5617
- CLOB CONVERSION TIME2 ms: 30.062757 Character: 5618
- CLOB CONVERSION TIME1 ms: 0.03323 Character: 3995
- CLOB CONVERSION TIME2 ms: 0.014769 Character: 3996
- CLOB CONVERSION TIME1 ms: 0.025846 Character: 3414
- CLOB CONVERSION TIME2 ms: 0.023795 Character: 3415

Have you try to use the statement

```
select dbms_lob.substr(dettXML__C, 4000, 1) from TABLE
```